# History of Location

Tags: iphone

**Problem**

I would like to know the places a device of mine has been in.

**Question**

Is there any way to get the history of locations with my iphone 5s?

Comment: Which version of iOS do you have installed?

Comment: @nohillside 12.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You can use the Apple Find My iPhone service to track and find your missing Apple device.

> **Use Find My iPhone**
>
> When you sign in to iCloud.com or the Find My iPhone app, you can see your missing device on a map or play a sound. And you can use Lost Mode to lock, track, or remotely erase all of your personal information.
>
> [More information on apple.com](https://support.apple.com/explore/find-my-iphone-ipad-mac-watch)

**Option 2:**

If the device is currently in your possession and location services are turned on:

Use Significant Locations settings’ to check visited places. These are buried pretty deep. You’ll find them in **Settings > Privacy > Location Services > System Services > Significant Locations**. You must authenticate yourself to see them, using your passcode, Touch ID or Face ID.

Comment: @santimirandarp Please specify your question. Just follow the steps above. Everything should be displayed on your device.

Comment: Is there any way to export this information to a file?

Comment: @santimirandarp I think that is not possible.

Comment: I only see there items under recent records and no apparent way to access more even though 260 are counted in the summary. Am I missing something?